# Delete the last record in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to delete the last database record but when I press the link, the page just refreshes and I dont get anything :/

Here's my controller:

```
  def delete
    @todo_items = Todo.last
    @todo_items.delete
  end
```

& here's my view

```
<h1>Shared Todo App</h1>
  <p>All your todos here</p>
<% @todo_items.each do |t| %>
<li><%= t.todo_item %>
<% end %>

  <%= link_to 'Delete', todo_item, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your action name should be `destroy`, not `delete`. A link with `method: :delete` will by default map to an action named `destroy`. See this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for details.

Second, you probably want to redirect somewhere at the end of your `destroy` action. For example, `redirect_to root_path`, or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: I plan to put a redirect in once this is working but it still just refreshes the page when I click delete.

There's no indication in the console either that a delete attempt has been made. So it look's like my controller code is at fault here but I can't see the issue :/

Comment: Do you have javascript disabled by any chance? If you use `method: :delete` in a `link_to` with javascript disabled, the request will fall back to `GET` instead of `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error when following the [same tutorial](http://www.codelearn.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial/how-to-add-actions-views-in-rails)

I changed my controller to:

```
def destroy
@todo_items = Todo.last
@todo_items.destroy
end
```

and changed the name of my view to destroy.html.erb.

This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Controller action should be `:destroy`

```
def destroy
  @todo_items = Todo.last
  @todo_items.delete
end
```

as Rails has 7 actions, which includes: `new`, `show`, `edit`, `index`, `destroy` and `update`.

Hence request will be for `destroy` action. So try this, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, your action should be called destroy, but that's not hte problem here.
If the page is only refreshing, it means it's not calling the DELETE method, or else you should see an "action not found" error or Rails should run the default destroy method.

Your problem is probably with javascript. Make sure you have it enabled and that on the application.html.erb page you have the following import:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

Or at least, the rails.js file, which is the one that makes the link_to method work when you change the default method:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails" %>
```